# Generating a controller and route that accepts parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a controller from the command line.

The route that's created is

```
GET    /cities_by_state/list(.:format)
```

and I'm trying to get

```
GET    /cities_by_state/list/:id(.:format)
```

How do I get Rails to create a route that accepts a parameter?

(Edited to add slash)

Comment: Why that particular route? What problem are you trying to solve here? The route that would define would be `/cities_by_state/list2`, for example.

Comment: @RyanBigg, I'm trying to return a list of cities based on the id of a state that I pass. I realize I left out a slash in there and just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
get 'cities_by_state/:state' => 'controller#action'
```

Comment: Okay, this works and that's fine. But when I'm generator a controller, how would I get this to work without having to add this explicitly to the routes file?

Comment: I don't think you can with the default generators. The routes generated are usually very basic anyway.